# Maintain position on web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit, tabcontainer

I hope I have done my homework on this one. I have a fairly large web application and when a button is pressed the webpage jumps to the top of the page on postback. I am aware that the page needs the line `MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true"`

So I went back to first principles and built two web pages. One has an ajax control tookit tabcontainer the second one has not.

On the one with the tabcontainer the maintainposition attribute has no affect and the page jumps back to the tabcontainer. On the one without ajax it works fine. Both pages are below.

Can you please tell me why and how I fix this issue?

**Webpage that does maintain position on postback**

```
%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="MaintainMyPosition.WebForm1" MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true"  %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        This Web Application will maintain the position on postback</div>
                <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />    
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Press me and position will be maintained" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Webpage that does NOT maintain position on postback**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm2.aspx.cs" Inherits="MaintainMyPosition.WebForm2" MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true"  %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" LoadScriptsBeforeUI="True">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <div>   
        This Web Application will NOT maintain the position on postback
        </div>                          
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:TabContainer ID="TabContainerMain" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="4" Width="100%"
                        Height="100%" CssClass="" ViewStateMode="Enabled">

                        <asp:TabPanel ID="Tab_Errors" runat="server" HeaderText="Tab_Errors">
                            <ContentTemplate>
                                <div class="TabControls">
                                    <p>
                                        Hello Im an ajax control tab and I'm going to cause this webpage to not maintain position .</p>
                                </div>
                            </ContentTemplate>
                        </asp:TabPanel>                                             
                    </asp:TabContainer>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />

    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Press me and position will not be maintained" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would suggest learning CSS. Using BRs to format a page is just plain wrong.

Comment: hi, this is a demo only to explain the issue. i do use of course css in my actual application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This article should explain it:

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/asp-net/7dd57635-0587-42ba-ae73-f52449e653bf/aspnet-ajax-maintain-scroll-position-from-a-partial-page-update.aspx

Comment: ok - ill try this out, i am interested into how i am supposed to cope with multiple controls on the form. i will report back.